# Python: Adding Float formatted time to datetime value

Tags: python, datetime

I want to add a randomly generated time value to an existing `datetime` object. Now, the time value that I have is a float. For example, I want to add `4.1326742` hours to `'2016-11-17'`. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why someone would downvote this. Yes, it might be a simple question for those who already know  about the datetime module but the docs are convoluted and would take time to fully comprehend for those who has not used them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to construct a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) and add it:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17)
>>> delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=4.1326742)
>>> d + delta
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 17, 4, 7, 57, 627120)
```

Comment: >>> from datetime import timedelta